# Cannot debug with gdb in ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

Qt creator throws an error every time I want to start debugging. Here is the error:

```
ptrace: Operation not permitted.

Could not attach to the process. Make sure no other debugger traces this process.
Check the settings of
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
```

I have googled the error message and got some result about bug in the kernel but I am able to run `gdb` in command line, so I don't think it is kernel/gdb related.

What can be the cause of this error?

Comment: What platform is this for?

Comment: @Merlin069 Well, it's ubuntu 12.04 and qt creator version 3.0.1. Kernel version is 3.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did some research and found the solution somewhere. It turns out that `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` was set to 1. After I changed it to 0, the problem disappeared.

Explanations of ptrace can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146160/what-is-the-ptrace-scope-workaround-for-wine-programs-and-are-there-any-risks) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process), as Merlin069 said.

Comment: ptrace_scope is explained here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41629/after-upgrade-gdb-wont-attach-to-process and here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/146160/what-is-the-ptrace-scope-workaround-for-wine-programs-and-are-there-any-risks

Comment: No problem. I suggest you mark this question as answered, if you're happy with it ;O)